# REST api call using method getbyemail for user in a group returns error “Cannot find resource for the request getbytitle”

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, groups, api

Users exist in sharepoint group:
[image]

If I do simple GET request in browser:
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite2/_api/web/sitegroups/getbytitle('TestGroup')/users/getbyemail('john.theuser@mycompany.com')

Returns error: *"Cannot find resource for the request getbytitle."*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request should be using `GetByName` instead of `GetByTitle`

So your request should be:
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite2/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('TestGroup')/users/getbyemail('john.theuser@mycompany.com')

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432%28v%3doffice.15%29

Comment: Wow. Thanks. Don't know where I got hold of `GetByTitle`

Comment: My code: https://pastebin.com/ZAJyCxVS

I was making api call to remove user from SP group on delete button onclick. It was working fine but i changed **getbytitle** to **getbyname** and strangely _click_ function has stopped working. Debugger doesn't work now inside onclick

List view: https://imgur.com/z3m1h9O

Comment: I think this one warrants a question of its own, how is the code injected?

Comment: Code injected inside **AllItems.aspx** page via SP Designer... under `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` tag. Works fine and stops under anything inside `$(document).ready` but click never gets triggered

Comment: Maybe some other event handler that overrides it? Again, you should create a new question for this to get more attention to it. I don't do much work with classic pages :-)

Comment: May I ask.. what is today's norm regarding sharepoint development. Is it through developing Visual studio Addins or Flow/Powerapps etc? How do we manipulate modern pages in SP?

Comment: [SharePoint Framework](http://aka.ms/spfx)!

Comment: @RuneSperre Which, unfortunately, requires an internet connection, getting Node.js, NPM to install Gulp, Yeoman, then downloading MS templates to manipulate in a code editor, compile with Gulp, put the output into an App Catalog site you have to build and have an admin group maintain where admins publish your apps from. Then add your app to the site. A huge hassle, and impossible on a disconnected network. MS is so dumb and this will kill SP upgrading in the government space. But that's just fine with me.